# PageReference construction returns community path

Tags: visualforce, community, url, experience-cloud

I am using the following code to extract some translations from a Visualforce Page

```
PageReference pr = Page.existingPage;
pr.getParameters().put(PARAM_LANGUAGE, language);
pr.getParameters().put(PARAM_INFO, info);
List<String> content = pr.getContent().toString().trim();
```

This code is being invoked in context of community guest user and as a logged-in user.
For both it works fine on sandboxes, but when it got deployed to prod and the custom domain was set up for the community it stopped working.
Let's say we have a domain `www.myexampledomain.com` configured for the community. The code works fine.
But when invoked on the default `www.myexampleorg.force.com/MyCommunityPath` domain the code starts suddenly return an URL for the `Page.existingPage` statement as `www.myexampleorg.force.com/MyCommunityPath/apex/existingPage` (so the host is the internal URL but with the community suffix) even though on sandboxes it works fine.
I can not even do a replace on this url to remove the community suffix as `getUrl()` method returns relative path as `/apex/existingpage` without this suffix and it fails only on invoking `getContent()` method where we get code 500 for non existing url.

Any ideas how to build the url to the visualforce page so it works for guest/internal/external users and on custom/standard domains?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue you are facing is related to the URL of the Visualforce page, specifically when it is being accessed from a community with a custom domain. One way to approach this problem is to create a new instance of the PageReference class and specify the URL explicitly, instead of using the Page.existingPage reference.

Here's an example of how you could modify your code to use this approach:

```
String pageUrl = '/apex/existingPage';
if (System.Site.getSiteType() == System.SiteType.portal) {
    // Community user
    if (System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost().endsWith('.force.com')) {
        // Internal community URL
        pageUrl = '/MyCommunityPath' + pageUrl;
    } else {
        // Custom community domain URL
        pageUrl = '/existingPage';
    }
}
PageReference pr = new PageReference(pageUrl);
pr.getParameters().put(PARAM_LANGUAGE, language);
pr.getParameters().put(PARAM_INFO, info);
List<String> content = pr.getContent().toString().trim();
```

In this modified code, we first check whether the current context is a community user or not, by using the System.Site.getSiteType() method. If it is a community user, we then check whether the URL of the Salesforce base URL ends with ".force.com". If it does, we assume that it is an internal community URL and append the community path to the page URL. Otherwise, we assume that it is a custom community domain URL and use the page URL directly.

By using this approach, we can dynamically construct the correct URL for the Visualforce page based on the current context, and avoid the issue with the Page.existingPage reference returning an incorrect URL.

**Another way**

you can try using the PageReference class's setUrl() method to set the URL explicitly.

Here's an example of how you can build the URL dynamically based on the context:

```
PageReference pr = new PageReference('');
if (Site.isGuest()) {
    pr.getParameters().put(PARAM_LANGUAGE, language);
    pr.getParameters().put(PARAM_INFO, info);
    pr.setUrl('/apex/existingPage');
} else {
    pr = Page.existingPage;
}
String url = pr.getUrl();
```

In this example, if the user is a guest user, we set the parameters and the URL explicitly using the setUrl() method. Otherwise, we use the existingPage variable as before. Finally, we retrieve the URL using the getUrl() method.

By using this approach, you can ensure that the URL is built correctly regardless of the user type or domain.

Comment: Hi Ali, thank you for the answer! I think you got me wrong, the URL should *never* contain the community path, as it should always point to internal vfp page. 
For guest users it works fine in all cases as technically it's an internal user and the url built using Page.existingPage is correct and does not contain the community path. For community users though, referencing by Page.existingPage returns the community sufix combined with internal host name so the URL is invalid when launching from standard community url on prod only.